# Artemis Authorization migration from ActiveMQ

Tags: authentication, activemq-artemis

My ActiveMQ uses an authentication plugin as shown below:

```xml
<plugins>
    <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
        <users>
            <authenticationUser username="${activemq.username}" password="${activemq.password}"
                                groups="admins,publishers,consumers"/>
            <authenticationUser username="${admin.username}" password="${admin.password}"
                                groups="admins,publishers,consumers"/>
        </users>
    </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

Could you say how ActiveMQ Artemis should handle this?

Comment: Hi Justin... I need to get the Web console access first before configuring the user access

Comment: Normal messaging users and web console users are configured the same way. Can you clarify why you need to configure web console access first before configuring messaging user access?

Comment: Hi Justin... with multiple broker users - Can the broker run command take the desired user ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify your question? Remember, you can always use `help` on the command-line (e.g. `artemis help user`).

Comment: Justin.. with multiple users in the artemis-users.properties ... can I run the broker for any user in the file i.e. artemis run --user= myAdminUser  - This way during deployment a variable can be used to select the user

Comment: Justin - each time we install and create a broker a new user.properties file is created so all the users added in previous instance are lost ... for this reason a user.properties file must be passed in after broker create command

Comment: The `run` command doesn't take a `--user` parameter. What do you mean "run the broker for any user"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question to clarify your use-case. This seems like a different question than the one you've posted here. The comments section really isn't the place to ask brand new questions. Comments are mainly meant to clarify the existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to configure user credentials in ActiveMQ Artemis as discussed in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html). However, the default, and probably simplest, way is via the `artemis-users.properties` and `artemis-roles.properties` files in the broker instance's `etc` directory. Given your example, you would configure them as follows...

Each line in `artemis-users.properties` follows the pattern of `<user> = <password>`:

```
myUser = myPassword
myAdminUser = myAdminPassword
```

The passwords can be hashed if you like so they aren't in plain-text. Simply use the command: `artemis mask --hash <password>`. You can take the output of that command and encapsulate it in `ENC()`, e.g.:

```
myUser = ENC(1024:D39BB78A7F474C285FA0F2B7AC1D8C4ABB4FAC3C6E49232CED3BDB489660E3CE:C9952A7B86EF49D38EF14F5FEDDC2BECC035E3C96F612302623AE2FDAF8D1DEEB298FEC4A07D6381557407C141D5756FF68C33AE88AE9934BAD01A82DC913E31)
```

More details can be found in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/masking-passwords.html).

Each line in `artemis-roles.properties` follows the pattern of `<role> = <users>`:

```
admins = myUser, myAdminUser
publishers = myUser, myAdminUser
consumers = myUser, myAdminUser
```

Once the broker is running these files can be modified directly or via the management API (e.g. via the web console or Jolokia). Management is also exposed via the `artemis user` command available from the command line. Modifications made during runtime are reflected in the broker by default.

Comment: Justin -if I add users and re-deploy the users are lost ... Can I copy in a user.properties file  to the broker-instance/etc after broker creation ?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can copy any configuration files you want to the instance's `etc` directory. It's all just text.

Comment: when I run the broker after creation ... is there a way to select the user I want (for example i may wish to run for adminuser or systemuser or any other user listed in my user.properties ) ...?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You don't run a broker for or with any user defined in `user.properties`.

Comment: Ok ...what is the purpose of the user ..is it just for the web console ?

Comment: Maybe they JMS clients must specify the user

Comment: The broker is secured by default so that any remote access requires the appropriate credentials. This includes web users *and* messaging users.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Justin - the default role for my broker user is "amq" ... can i alter the role that is provided as defaul since amq role does not seem to give permissions